# LAPACK with gcc startup guide

Tags: gcc, lapack

I need help to setup LAPACK in Linux gcc. I am new to LAPACK and have no knowledge in using Fortran.

I have downloaded lapack-3.4.0, and make the libraries to get 
  liblapack.a and librefblas.a.

Afterwards, i link these libraries to my program: 
  -llapack -lrefblas

I wanted to use the LAPACK functions like dpotrf, dgetrf, dgetri etc,
How do I include the header files in order for my compiler to find the functions? Is it neccessary for me to use lapacke, a C interface to LAPACK?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of using LAPACK with c++. Here's what I'd do (assuming you are on some *nix system).

1. Make sure you have the right libraries and you know the right set of compiler/linker options. Since these are written in Fortran, I'd start with a Fortran code. Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637888/where-can-i-find-blas-example-code-in-fortran/4640318#4640318). Make sure you can compile it using `gfortran`. Possible linker options can be (depending on your system): `-llapack`, `-lblas` or some combinations of these.
2. Then move onto using C++ interface. Again, there are multiple ways of doing. I personally find it the easiest to use the clapack interface, where you are declaring the LAPACk functions like this:

`extern "C" void dsyev_( char *jobz, char *uplo, int &n, double *a, int &lda, double *w, double *work, int &lwork, int &info);`

The right set of linker options again depends on your system and can be something like this: `-llapack -lf77blas -latlas` (this set works on my Ubuntu where LAPACK comes from the `atlas` package).